# Using paths in different packages convenient way

Tags: go

I have a program in which I use a lot "../" which is to go one level up
in the file system and run some process on the directory with specific name. I have a command line tool in Go.

I have 3 questions

> 1. there is nicer way to do it instead of “../“
> 2. is there a const with which I can use instead of “/“
> 3. if 2 is not available should I create “constants“  under that internal package to share the “/“ between packages since I need it in
>      many place (from diff packages...)

example

```
   dir.zip("../"+tmpDirName, "../"+m.Id+".zip", "../"+tmpDirName)
```

Comment: As fas I understand GO, you dont have to create many packages as others OO languages. Take a look at some repos in Github

Comment: Let's see some code. "/" is already a constant.

Comment: @Peter - see my update, I use it in different place's in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set a variable, and use that everywhere:

   ```
   path := "../"
   ```

   or

   ```
   path := ".." + string(os.PathSeparator)
   ```

   then later:

   ```
   dir.zip(path+tmpDirName, path+m.Id+".zip", path+tmpDirName)
   ```

   This makes it very easy to change the path in the future, via a command line option, configuration, or just editing the value.
2. Yes. [os.PathSeparator](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-constants) is the OS-specific path separator for the current architecture.
3. n/a

Comment: Thank you, but for the first suggestion I need to define it in several different files, why it's better then creating constants file which I can share and use  in different files

Comment: Using a constants file makes perfect sense to me in that case.

Answer (score 0):

1. declare a global const somewhere, but I would just use ".." everywhere
2. os.PathSeparator
3. use `filepath.Join("..", someDir, someFilename)`